# Successor and Predecessor worst-case running time in dynamic sets

Tags: data-structures, clrs

What is the asymptotic worst-case running time for the following dynamic-set operations ?

Successor(L,x) for unsorted singly & doubly linked lists

Predecessor(L,x) for unsorted doubly linked list

L: list , x: pointer to an entry

(Actually this is part of the question 10-1 of the book : "Introduction to Algorithms, third edition" , I searched for the answer , the answer is O(n) but I couldn't find any explanation for it)

Answer (score 0):

With "predecessor" and "successor", I suppose you mean in sorted order.

It is indeed O(n) because you need to look at each element of the list to find it.

Comment: But I guess that in Linked List the Predecessor and Successor means the elements which are right after/before the current element , the value does not matter

Comment: Yeah, I considered that too but if that is really the case, then this entire exercise is completely trivial (and the "sample solution" would make no sense).